# What does it mean by catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) when (!TodoItemExists(id))?

Tags: c#, .net

What does the below code block mean:

```
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) when (!TodoItemExists(id))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
```

Full sample:

```
// PUT: api/TodoItems/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateTodoItem(long id, TodoItemDTO todoItemDTO)
{
    if (id != todoItemDTO.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);
    if (todoItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    todoItem.Name = todoItemDTO.Name;
    todoItem.IsComplete = todoItemDTO.IsComplete;

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) when (!TodoItemExists(id))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when). In your case, when the exception is thrown the code returns `NotFound()` if the item doesnt exist. Think of this as combining `if` inside `catch` block?

Comment: This is an Put (Update) endpoint, so what situation exactly does this exception handle please?

Comment: When you make a call to `SaveChangesAsync` and it failed due to `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` thrown, the code returns `NotFound` if `TodoItemExists(id)` returns `false`. i.e iF your insert/updates to db failed, you are checking at the time of exception whether the item exists? If it doesnt exist, you return `NotFound`.

Comment: Ok so this is just to confirm that someone hasn't already deleted that record?

Answer (score 1):

This is called an *exception filter* clause. It is normally used like this:

```cs
// without exception filters:
try 
{
    var file = new StreamReader(myInputStream);
    // ....
}
catch (IOException x)
{
    // Handle error
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException x)
{
    // Handle error (same as above)
}
catch (SocketException x)
{
    // Handle error (again, same as above)
}
// etc., etc...

// Instead, one can write
try
{
    var file = new StreamReader(myInputStream);
    // ....
}
catch (Exception x) when (x is SocketException || x is UnauthorizedAccessException || x is IOException)
{
   // Handle all expected exception types in one handler
}
```

I have never seen it being used as in your example. And I'm not sure it is used correctly. What it does is that it only enters the `catch` clause when `TodoItemsExists` returns false. That means, on the other hand, that if a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown and `TodoItemsExists` returns true, the catch handler is *not* invoked and the exception falls trough, eventually crashing the server task.

I'm not sure about the actual requirement, but I think the following is intented instead:

```cs
try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!TodoItemExists(id))
        {
             return NotFound();
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
```

So this will return the appropriate error message to the caller (either `NotFound()` or `NoContent()`) when the exception is thrown.

The condition in the `when` clause can be used to do an additional test whether the handler should be invoked.

Comment: The example is from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

Comment: In an example block a few lines above, they write the same without the exception filter, and they really rethrow the exception there. If that's the intent, then those two blocks are identical.